# Pythonのファイル構造と生産性について(多数クラスの取り扱い)

Tags: python

現在Java等を中心に開発を行っていますが、今後一部の開発プロジェクトでPythonを利用していこうと考えています。諸々特性を調査をした結果、中規模以上(複数人)の開発で、懸念を感じ質問です。

Pythonでは「1ファイル=1クラス」の構造では開発しないと思いますが、"大量クラスが作られるオブジェクト指向開発"で生産性に影響はないでしょうか？

(案件としては、計算ライブラリ/AIライブラリ等を利用した機能をウェブのシステムに追加する可能性のある案件を想定してます)

ご教授 or 意見を頂きたいです。

Comment: pythonはオブジェクト指向をサポートしてますしダックタイピングもサポートしていますが、C++やJavaの典型的な例のようにクラスを量産するという方向性ではないと思います、例えばJavaでいうところのthis.を省略できるように設計されていません、Javaの流儀をpythonに持ち込もうとしてもうまくいかない気がします。Javaのように静的型チェックが働くわけでもなく、パフォーマンスを引き出すためには対策が必要ですが、動的型付けにおける品質保証に対する戦略を持っていますか。pythonを使用する主目的を明確に語っていただいたほうが良いと思われます。

Answer (score 2):

Pythonは大規模システムの開発にも十分使えるプログラム言語ですが、Javaで書かれた大量のクラスがあるプログラムをそのままPythonに移行させることは、次のような理由であまり適当だとは思いません。

- 処理速度が遅くなる
- 型チェックができなくなる

Pythonを使いたいのであれば、グルー言語である特徴をいかして、使いたい部分のみをPythonにした方がいいと思います。例えば、Javaで書いていたコードを外部のサービスを使いたい場合やPythonにはデータサイエンスや機械学習の分野を中心に優秀なライブラリーがありますがそのライブラリーを使いたい場合です。

PythonとJavaのプログラム間のやり取りについては、従来からの方法の他に`gRPC`や`JSON-RPC`が使えるので困ることはないと思います。

Comment: 回答の件、全般的に共感します。十分納得できていない点としては、「大規模開発」かつ「オブジェクト指向言語」であるにも関わらず、「大量クラス作成が不向きである可能性がある点」です。"ある程度の規模"になるとクラスが多数出現する事は不可避と考えており、中規模以上の開発に不安を感じます。

Comment: ニュアンスを少し変えるため「大規模開発」を「大規模システムの開発」に変更しておきました。Pythonで大規模システムを開発する場合は、マイクロサービスを組み合わせて作るケースで使われている場合が多いと思います。